# Page refuses to refresh unless request made by URL bar

Tags: jquery, firefox, material-design-lite

[Closed Topic : see answer below]

I'm on Firefox 60.6.1 esr (32 bit) and I'm not likely to update since I'm in a corporate environment. I've tested on Edge and Chrome and the problem seems to occur only on Firefox. I've got no errors in console.

I've got a page that completely refuses to refresh via keyboard shortcuts like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>, <kbd>F5</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Maj</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, and even via pressing the reload button. Only way the page reloads is by resending the same URL in the URL bar.

I have mouse event listeners on checkboxes and buttons, and a keyup event listener on a search bar that sends AJAX calls to update a data table. Everything worked fine when I've added those, the problem just seemingly appeared out of nowhere.

So my question is "Is there a way to actually make this happen through code or is it a software related issue ?"

Hope someone can help

Edit :

My Event Listeners looks like that :

```
    $("#view table.table-horizontal-scroll").on("mouseup", function(event){
/* Show snackbar when checkboxes are checked */
}

    $("li.mdl-menu__item").on('click', function(evt){
/* updates the buttons look (it just toggles 'is-active classes')*/
}

  $("div.mdl-filter-table tbody > tr > td:first-of-type").on("mouseup", function(evt){
  /* Apply filters through ajax calls and update the data table */
}


    $("#search-input").on("keyup", function(evt){
  /*Take my search-input value and apply it as a filter through an ajax call and updates the data table*/

  /*Also made it so I only take the input value when the user didn't type in it for the last 500ms*/
}

    $("li[id^='view']").on('click', function(e){
/* updates how many rows are displayed in data table*/
}
```

Comment: `I might have made an error in my code that is making this happen` That's likely the problem, but without seeing any of the code we can't really help you. Do you have any key-based event listeners which prevent the event from occurring?

Comment: Also note that I removed the PHP tag as this is a client-side issue.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have mouse event listeners on checkboxes and buttons, and a keyup event listener on a search bar that sends AJAX calls to update a data table. Everything worked fine when I've added those, the problem just seemingly appeared out of nowhere (also should I edit my post to add what I just said ?)

Comment: You could add that to explain the issue some more, but without seeing the code no one can help you.

Comment: Well, thing is I've got 300+ lines of JS into it, and I doubt just C/C-ing it all will help. Maybe snippets of it, but then which ones ? Sorry if I sound really dumb, I'm kinda new into this whole thing
Also I've edited my post so it reflects more what I'm actually wondering

Comment: Given the behaviour search the codebase for key-based events (`keyup`, `keydown`, `keypress`, `input` etc) and check what they're doing.

Comment: Well that would make sense if only shortcuts weren't working, but even clicking on the reload button does nothing. My question is more about "What are the ways this could happen" because I assume there aren't that many, and it's not about "Why doesn't it work with my specific code ?"

Comment: Edited post with what are my eventListeners. Also checked my ajax calls if it came from them not completing, but they're fine.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so it's no at all related to software or code in any way, and I feel even dumber now.

I talked about my problem to some colleagues that are at helpdesk, and just went with the reflex "Have you tried turning your computer off and on again ?"

Gave it a try... It worked.

The weird thing is that it would happen only to this page, and no others (and I've got a tons of tabs opened).

Anyway, have a great day, thanks to those who took the time to read my post and try to help me.